# Submit to cluster queue from local computer

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, torque

It is possible to submit to a cluster run using a Maui scheduler from a remote machine that's on the same network as the login/head node? The remote machine is on the same network and has the same users, groups, and network mounts as the login node.

How would one go about configuring this on the remote machine?

Comment: Did you read the "[Configuring job submission hosts](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-1-3/Content/topics/1-installConfig/serverConfig.htm#configJobSubHost)" section of the Torque manual?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Torque, then you want the [qsub](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm) command. If the qsub command isn't present or isn't configured, then you'd need to talk to your system administrator to get it set up as a submission node, or perhaps get directed to submission nodes.